# An injection yields an isomorphism in cohomology? $\Bbb RP^n \rightarrow \Bbb RP^{\infty}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

In [page 79  line 10](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html) Hatcher made the claim that

> An embedding $\Bbb RP^{n-1} \rightarrow \Bbb RP^\infty$ induces an isomoprhism 
>   $$H^i(\Bbb RP^n, \Bbb Z_2) \leftarrow H^i(\Bbb RP^\infty, \Bbb Z_2)$$
>   for $i\le n$.

I know both cohomology groups are isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$. I also know this holds when we have the canonical cell inclusion from cellular cohomology. But I don't understand how this is true for arbitrary embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take any open contractible subset $U$ of a manifold $M$, the injection $U\rightarrow M$ does not necessarily induces an isomorphism on any cohomology group. The CW-structure on $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ is the limit of the CW-structure on $\mathbb{R}P^n$. The injection $\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ identifies the $i$-cell of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with the $i$-cell of $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$, $i<n+1$. this enables to show that result.

Comment: Sorry, may you elaborate more? I still don't see how the result follows.

Comment: So we build  the CW structure of $\Bbb RP^\infty$ out of the image of $\Bbb RP^n$?

Comment: Yes, it is built like that write $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ has limit of $\mathbb{R}P^n$, then the injection $\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^m, n<m$ enables to identify the $i$-cells of $\mathbb{R}P^m$ with th $i$-cells of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ where $i\leq n$.